# Waypoints – jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm getting a bunch of errors when using Waypoints. Everything is behaving as it should, except enableAll(), despite disableAll() working as it should. The main errors are:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

I am building my Waypoints from an array, which is what I think is causing the problem. The array contains IDs which I am then adding a string to to create a corresponding Waypoint:

```
var links = ['#id1', '#id2', '#id3', '#id4'];
$(document).ready(function () {
$.each(links, function (p, linkP) {
        var inview = new Waypoint.Inview({
            element: $(linkP + 'Content'),
            ...
```

Comment: maybe [this](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/issues/403) helps *The element option in Waypoints expects a plain ol' element* whereas you are setting it as a jQuery object

Comment: I saw that, but couldn't make it applicable to my code as I need to create the Waypoints in this way. Is there a way I can parse $(linkP + 'Content') as an element and "trick" the element option into thinking it's a "plain ol' element"?

Comment: `$(linkP + 'Content')[0]`

Comment: That's worked, thank you so much! I'm not sure what the [0] does though in this context...?

Comment: it's the first element (DOM element) that matches the selector supplied